# PostgreSQL display size of a table being created

Tags: postgresql

We have an application going on for more than four years and a lot of data was being accumulated during this period. With the push for new features all this time, implementing archiving and clean up procedures where pushed back again and again.

Deleting records with `DELETE` statements was no longer an option as it would have taken forever. So we created a script that was acting in a more aggressive way by creating a temporary table with the records we wanted to keep (last month of data) then dropping the original table then renaming the temporary table to the right name and recreating the constrains and indexes, etc

```
CREATE TABLE fred_to_keep AS SELECT * FROM fred WHILE last_update < current_date - 31 * INTERVAL '1 day';
DROP TABLE fred;
ALTER TABLE fred_to_keep RENAME TO fred;
-- create indexes and constraints here, change the owner etc
```

Given the aggressive nature of our approach this was tested lots of times on databases with a similar data size and repartition with our production database and the overall time taken was about 2 and 1/2 hours. From the script logs one of the tables was taken one hour to clean up.

Then we decided to run it in production. Everything was going fine until it hit the table `fred` and after three hours the script was still not finished and we had to take the decision to kill the script and restore the database from the snapshot taken just before started. After waiting another half an hour we had no choice but to do the rollback.

Now coming from an Oracle background I know it is possible by interrogating `dba_segments` to see the table size increasing while it is being created. Trying to google for a similar thing in PostreSQL did not take me anywhere and I am wondering is there any way to actually see the progress of `CREATE TABLE AS SELECT * FROM fred WHERE ...` while this is being executed? Being able to see the space taken by the table being created and comparing it against expected size would have helped us to take a much more informed decision about killing the script or leaving it run. It is a bad feeling to think we killed it maybe just one minute before finishing.

Comment: 1) Why not set up [Partitioning](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-partitioning.html)? 2) See [Admin functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-admin.html) *9.27.7. Database Object Management Functions*.

Comment: Partitioning by date then dropping old partitions. This is an approach that we could try and a good suggestion. But my question is about ways of monitoring table creation progress

Comment: And I pointed you at the functions that can help with that. Or you can get the `relfilenode` from [pg_class](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/catalog-pg-class.html) and monitor the file directly from the disk.

Comment: We won't have access to the database server to monitor file size. But would pg_relation_size('table_in_progress') work? I can try this myself on Monday, too tired now after sitting here all night but if you know it works pls post your suggestion as an answer and I'll accept it as soon as I test and confirm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Example of using `pg_relation_size()` to monitor table size.

```
create table dog(id integer);

select pg_relation_size('dog');
 pg_relation_size 
------------------
                0

insert into dog values (1);
select pg_relation_size('dog');
pg_relation_size 
------------------
             8192

insert into dog select * from generate_series(1, 100000);
select pg_relation_size('dog');
pg_relation_size 
------------------
          3629056
```

If you do this in a explicit transaction e.g. `Begin; <DDL, DML statements> Commit;` then other sessions will not be able to see/monitor until the `Commit` is done.

**UPDATE**

Potential work around for monitoring from other session.

```
--Session 1
BEGIN;
create table dog(id integer);
COMMIT;
--Session 1
BEGIN;
insert into dog values (1);
select pg_relation_size('dog');
 pg_relation_size 
------------------
             8192
...
--Session 2
select pg_relation_size('dog');
 pg_relation_size 
------------------
             8192
...
--Session 1
insert into dog select * from generate_series(1, 100000);
select pg_relation_size('dog');
 pg_relation_size 
------------------
          3629056
...
--Session 2
select pg_relation_size('dog');
 pg_relation_size 
------------------
          3629056
...
--Session 1
COMMIT;
```

Using on disk file to monitor.

```
BEGIN;
create table dog(id integer);
SELECT pg_relation_filepath(oid) FROM pg_class WHERE relname = 'dog';
 pg_relation_filepath 
----------------------
 base/59704/241012

-- ls -al base/59704/241012
-- -rw------- 1 postgres users 0 Jan 21 08:33 base/59704/241012

insert into dog values (1);

-- ls -al base/59704/241012
-- -rw------- 1 postgres users 8192 Jan 21 08:38 base/59704/241012

insert into dog select * from generate_series(1, 100000);

-- ls -al base/59704/241012
-- -rw------- 1 postgres users 3629056 Jan 21 08:39 base/59704/241012
```

Comment: Hmmmm. I am surprised such a basic thing is not supported. With Oracle if you have a long running insert which takes a lot of time to execute say hours you can always open a new session and run `SELECT bytes/1024/1024 FROM dba_segments WHERE segment_name = 'my_table'` and you can see how that number increases as the time goes. This is applicable even if the insert is running inside a transaction.

However you told me how you can work out which file stores the table data and monitoring that file you can make some calculations. Please add that to your answer and I'll accept it as a valid one.

Comment: See **UPDATE** for two other methods to monitor table size.

Answer (score 0):

If it is all done in one transaction, there is no good way to do this in postgresql from SQL, because until the creation of the table is committed, no one else can get there eyes on it. You can use file system tools to watch the file grow, but you first need to infer which file is the right one.  If you don't have access to the file system, I'm afraid you are out of luck.